# Berry curvature of a two band lattice Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, topology, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators

Consider a general two band lattice Hamiltonian, which can be expressed as a $2\times2$ matrix:
$$\mathcal{H}=\vec{h}(\vec{k})\cdot \vec{\sigma}$$ where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the vector of Pauli matrices. The berry curvature is $F(\vec{k})=\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial k_x}-\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial k_y}$, where the Berry connection is $A_\nu=i\vec{u}^*\cdot \partial_\nu \vec{u}$

I want to directly show that the Berry curvature can be alternatively written as $$F(\vec{k})=-\frac{1}{2}\vec{d}\cdot (\frac{\partial\vec{d}}{\partial k_x} \times \frac{\partial\vec{d}}{\partial k_y})$$ where $\vec{d}\equiv \vec{h}/h$ and $h\equiv |\vec{h}|$

The eigenvector for the lower eigenvalue $-h$ is $$\vec{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-2d_z}}\begin{pmatrix} d_z - 1 \\ d_x + id_z\end{pmatrix}$$
Substituting all the appropriate  expressions first by hand and then also using Mathematica, gives
$$ F=\frac{1}{2(d_z-1)^2}\Big[d_x((\partial_yd_z)(\partial_x d_y) - (\partial_xd_z)(\partial_y d_y))\\
+d_y((\partial_yd_x)(\partial_x d_z) - (\partial_yd_z)(\partial_x d_x))\\
+2(d_z-1)((\partial_xd_x)(\partial_y d_y) - (\partial_yd_x)(\partial_x d_y))\Big]$$
However, the expression should look something like this..
$$ F\propto d_x((\partial_yd_z)(\partial_x d_y) - (\partial_xd_z)(\partial_y d_y))\\
+d_y((\partial_yd_x)(\partial_x d_z) - (\partial_yd_z)(\partial_x d_x))\\
+d_z((\partial_xd_x)(\partial_y d_y) - (\partial_yd_x)(\partial_x d_y))$$

Not sure what I am missing here?